# Netbeans 8.2. Maven webapplication won't run on Tomcat but will on Glasfish server

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, restful-url

I am developing a simple restful server and want to deploy it on a Tomcat server. When I deploy the project it won't run and gives me the message: http 404, The requested resource is not available.

The project is a default, newly created Maven project and when I select Glasfish it runs fine. Can anyone give help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. For anyone struggling. Java Jax-RS doesn't run default on Tomcat. You need Tomcat EE or add EE to Tomcat.